# navigation property in sqlite with windows8 app

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8

This is my first time to use SQLite database in windows 8 app, I have two classes as below:

```
class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Parent Par { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to create a one to many relationship in these two class, and when I query out a Parent instance, I can get a list of the Child by par.Children property?
Another question, how to let the Id property auto increment as identity value?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem now and i start to try this "Devart LinqConnect for Metro"
http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/metro-database-access-with-linqconnect.html
http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/linqconnect-for-metro-quick-start-guide.html

Hope it helps you